# Reference request: Introduction to Finsler manifolds from the metric geometry point of view (possibly from the Busemann's approach)

Tags: reference-request, metric-geometry, finsler-geometry

This question is a **cross post** from [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333204/reference-request-introduction-to-finsler-manifolds-from-the-metric-geometry-po). I have requested the migration of the question, but unfortunately it is not possible after two months of posting.

I was reading about geometry in metric spaces from different books, two of them are: (1) *A course in metric geometry* by Y. Burago, D. Burago and S. Ivanov; and (2) *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature* by M. Bridson and A. Häfliger. Both develop the Alexandrov's approach to curvature, which uses comparison triangles with the constant curvature model spaces.

For a normed space $X$, the following statements are equivalent:

1. $X$ has curvature $\leq\kappa$ in Alexandrov's sense, for some real number $\kappa$.
2. $X$ has curvature $\leq 0$ in Alexandrov's sense.
3. The norm on $X$ is induced by an inner product.

So it seems to me that Alexandrov's approach is not very informative in the normed case. On the other hand, a geodesic space has non-positive curvature in the Busemann's sense if its metric is convex, in general this is a weaker notion than Alexandrov's, and in the normed case the following statements are equivalent:

1. $X$ has non-positive curvature in the Busemann's sense.
2. $X$ is uniquely geodesic, that is, every pair of points is joined by a unique geodesic (the linear segment between them).
3. $X$ is strinctly convex, that is, the ball in $X$ is strictly convex which means that for every pair of different vectors $v$ and $w$ of norm equal to $1$ we have that $tv+(1-t)w$ has norm strictly less than $1$ for every $t$ in $(0,1)$.

So it seems to me that this weaker notion is the appropriate notion for non-positive curvature in the normed case and I think also for finsler manifolds. **I have never studied finsler geometry, but I am very interested in studying metric geometry from this approach.** And I do not know where I should start.

> **My question is:** What is a good introductory book about finsler manifolds from the metric geometry point of view? What is a good introductory book for the Busemann's approach? If there was not an introductory book available, a reference to an advanced one along with references that cover the necessary background would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the following references:

1. An introductory textbook by A. Papadopoulos about the Busemann's approach: [Metric Spaces, convexity and non-positive curvature](https://books.google.com.ar/books/about/Metric_Spaces_Convexity_and_Nonpositive.html?id=JrwzXZB0YrIC&redir_esc=y).
2. A textbook by H. Busemann: [The geometry of geodesics](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-geometry-of-geodesics/busemann/978-0-12-374555-2)
3. Two interesting papers by H. Busemann: [The geometry of finsler spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183514449) and [Spaces with non-positive curvature](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485888482).

**EDIT**:

4. User @Matt F. in [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333204/reference-request-introduction-to-finsler-manifolds-from-the-metric-geometry-po/338801#338801) recommend *The Geometry of Geodesics* (1955), which includes almost all of the content of the other two papers mentioned above, and another Busemann's book, *Recent Synthetic Differential Geometry* (1970), with more advanced follow-ups from the intervening years.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the paper "On intrinsic geometry of surfaces in normed
spaces - Burago and Ivanov" which deals second variation on Finsler
surface, isometric embedding of Finsler surface and a geodesic line
on Finsler surface.